# Mount a Windows share on Linux boot without storing the password

Tags: redhat, network-share, rhel6

Is there a way to do this? Most examples store the credentials in an external file to fstab e.g. -

fstab:

```
\\server\share /media/windowsmount cifs credentials=/root/secret.txt,_netdev,uid=root,gid=dba 0 0
```

secret.txt:

```
username=sushi
password=yummy
```

The only way I can think of is maybe when Linux is joined to a Windows domain via winbind. It could use the machines Active Directory computer account credentials to authenticate to the Windows share but I don't know how or if this could be implemented for fstab or some other mechanism of mounting during boot.

I see something similar being done on ubuntu when user's ssh in with active directory credentials and PAM mount uses the user's credentials to mount a Windows Share. This is for user login, I'm looking to do the same kind of thing at boot on Redhat.

[How to authenticate Linux accounts against an Active Directory and mount a Windows share on login?](https://serverfault.com/questions/135396/how-to-authenticate-linux-accounts-against-an-active-directory-and-mount-a-windo)