# How do I mount a home catalog using cifs and autofs with Active Directory authentication on CentOS7?

Tags: active-directory, authentication, centos7, cifs, autofs

I'm trying to integrate a CentOS7 client with Active Directy authentication and automatically mounting the user homedirs with cifs.

I would prefer to use autofs, but I've so far been unable to make cifs mount work with sec=krb5 setting. It always fails with this message

```
# mount -t cifs //fileserver.my.domain/user  /mnt/user/ -orw,noperm,sec=krb5
mount error(126): Required key not available
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Any hints on getting autofs to work with cifs and AD would be most welcome.

Setting up the authentication was a no-brainer using [this description](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Windows_Integration_Guide/realmd-domain.html) from RedHat and just amounted to add the neccessary packages listed by

```
realm discover MY.DOMAIN
```

and running the command

```
realm join MY.DOMAIN -U ad-admin-username
```

So authentication works fine, but getting cifs and kerberos to work is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

I do have a workaround using pam_exec, but do not feel that mounting of file shares belongs in the pam framework.

By inserting the following lines into /etc/pam.d/password-auth the listed script at the end will mount the right homedir upon password authentication. A lazy unmount is performed at session_close, but might not be the right thing to do.

Put this into password-auth

```
auth        optional      pam_exec.so expose_authtok /usr/bin/pam_mount_cifs.s
```

and this

```
session     optional      pam_exec.so  /usr/bin/pam_mount_cifs.sh
```

both lines should be inserted after pam_mkhomedir lines inserted by the realm join command.

Another alternative is using pam_mount as described in [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/135396/how-to-authenticate-linux-accounts-against-an-active-directory-and-mount-a-windo), but then you must compile and install pam_mount manually as it is not provided with CentOS. (or get it from [the Nux repo](http://li.nux.ro/repos.html))

Here is the script itself, it shoud be saved as /usr/bin/pam_mount_cifs.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# this script is called from pam by adding entries to /etc/pam.d/password-auth like this
#
# auth      optional      pam_exec.so expose_authtok /usr/bin/pam_mount_cifs.sh
#
# and
#
# session   optional      pam_exec.so  /usr/bin/pam_mount_cifs.sh

# the script assumes that the home dir is already created by pam_mkhomedir and pam_oddjob_mkhomedir.


DOMAIN=my.domain
FILESERVER=fileserver.my.domain
MNTPNT=/home

# turn of globbing because getent returns as string containing a *
set -f

pwstring=$(getent passwd $PAM_USER)
userinfo=(${pwstring//:/ })
USER=$PAM_USER
# strip off @my.domain from user.
SHORTUSER=${USER%@$DOMAIN}
USERUID=${userinfo[2]}
USERGID=${userinfo[3]}

USERDIR=$MNTPNT/$USER

if [ -z "$PAM_TYPE" ]; then
    echo this script should only be called from pam
    exit 1
fi



if [ $PAM_TYPE = "open_session" ]; then
    # nothing to do here, mount happened in auth.
    exit 0
fi

if [ $PAM_TYPE = "close_session" ]; then
    # this might cause problems if you have services that doesn't create procs in /home. (rstudio is one example)
    umount -l $USERDIR
    exit 0
fi

if [ ! -d $USERDIR ]; then
    mkdir -p $USERDIR
#    chown $USERID:$USERGID $USERDIR
fi

# skip if the share is already mounted.
mountpoint -q $USERDIR && exit 0

# make mount.cifs read password from stdin
export PASSWD_FD=0
mount -t cifs //$FILESERVER/$SHORTUSER $USERDIR -o user=$SHORTUSER,uid=$USERUID,gid=$USERGID,noserverino
```